# Find missing words between two pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns with components and I want to compare if the new column has a word missing or different from the old column

**Col 1**

```
Index     Old
0         Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Treated Water, Caffeine, Flavour Enhancer
1         Natural Extracts, Glycol, Ethanol,
```

**Col 2**

```
Index     New
0         Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Water, Flavour Reducer
1         Glycol, Ethanol
```

I've tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work properly

```
L = df['old']
values_not_in_array = df[~df.old.isin(L)].old
values_in_array = df[df.old(L)].old
```

What's the best solution to create a column with values that's missing or different from old column that' not in new column row?

Comment: do u mind posting ur expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert splitted values to sets and subtract, last if necessary join to strings:

```
df['diff'] = [', '.join(set(o.split(', ')) - set(n.split(', '))) 
                                                          for o, n in zip(df.Old, df.New)]
print (df)
                                                 Old  \
0  Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Treated Wat...   
1                  Natural Extracts, Glycol, Ethanol   

                                                 New  \
0  Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Water, Flav...   
1                                    Glycol, Ethanol   

                                       diff  
0  Treated Water, Flavour Enhance, Caffeine  
1                          Natural Extracts
```

---

```
df['miss'] = [', '.join(set(n.split(', ')) - set(o.split(', '))) 
                                                           for o, n in zip(df.Old, df.New)]
print (df)
                                                 Old  \
0  Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Treated Wat...   
1                  Natural Extracts, Glycol, Ethanol   

                                                 New                    miss  
0  Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Water, Flav...  Water, Flavour Reducer  
1                                    Glycol, Ethanol
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by applying a method which will covert column value to list of word and then find the difference and save it in new column:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {
    'Old': ['Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Treated Water, Caffeine, Flavour Enhancer', 'Natural Extracts, Glycol, Ethanol,'],
    'New': ['Caramel Color, Color, Citric Acid, Water, Flavour Reducer', 'Glycol, Ethanol'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

print(df)

df['MissingWord'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(set(x['Old'].split(',')) - set(x['New'].split(',')))), axis=1)

print(df['MissingWord'])
```

**output:**

```
0     Treated Water,  Caffeine,  Flavour Enhancer
1                      Glycol, , Natural Extracts
Name: MissingWord, dtype: object
```